# CI for grouped data

Tags: confidence-interval

I have a continuous variable, that for measuring limitations comes in bins, i.e. instead of an exact value, I get "up to 20", "20-30", "30-40", "40-50", "more than 50". In every elementary class you learn to calculate the mean by taking the middle point of each class as representative. I want to estimate the mean and s.d, with CI's. How do I do that ? I couldn't find any reference online. The distribution is assumed to be normal. I want to characterize the distribution (mean, s.d.).

Comment: Seems like a case for ordinal regression, although its results are not trivial to interpret IMO

Comment: how will ordinal regression estimate means and sd's ? doesn't it estimate the odds with a reference group (among the ordinal categories) ?

Comment: You can treat the data as censored & use maximum likelihood to estimate the mean $\mu$ & std deviation $\sigma$. So each observation in e.g. the 20-30 class contributes a factor $F(30; \mu, \sigma) - F(20; \mu, \sigma)$ to the likelihood, where $F(\cdot)$ is the normal distribution function.